# I want to encode Chinese to \\u5de5\\u4f5c formate in php.

Tags: php

I want to encode Chinese to \u5de5\u4f5c formate in php. is there any builtin php function or any method to do that ?

Comment: It si unclear what you ask. What do you mean by "\u5de5\u4f5c formate"?

Comment: @arkascha He's talking about unicode

Comment: @Swivelgames Might well be. Nevertheless the OP should clarify what is meant. It makes little sense to _guess_ the questions meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `json_encode()` can be used to escape UTF-8 encoded strings into UNICODE format.

Example:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode('工作');
```

Output:

```
"\u5de5\u4f5c"
```

Comment: http://codepad.org/lUxR8MMb

Comment: Yeap, looks like it works. Why the downvote?

Comment: and if i want to decode then json_decode not works for me i want this string 
\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83
to back chinese i use 
json_decode('\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83');

it not works for me
any idea for it

Comment: Thats a good question. `json_encode()` not only converts and escapes the string, it also returns it wrapped with commas `""`, and `json_decode()` will expect similar input. So the right way is `json_decode('"\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83"')` (notice the double wrapping).